# How to always display the Product attribute label in English in the Additional information tabs in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to add some styling to the product additional information table.
To do so, i have added the product attribute label to the standard table layout file located in:

> app/design/frontend/my_theme/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
  <?php $lbl = $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label']))?>
  <tr class="<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $lbl)) ?>">
    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></th>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the problem with this is that te label gets translated to the store language. Is there a way to force the label to always display in English?

Much appreciated!

Comment: set attribute label storewise  in backend attribute manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're better off using the attribute code instead of the attribute label if you just need an identifier. The attribute code is universal across all storeviews.

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
  <?php $code = $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['code']))?>
  <tr class="<?php echo $code; ?>">
    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></th>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove $this->__() from string

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
  <?php $lbl = $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label']))?>
  <tr class="<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $lbl)) ?>">
    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></th>
    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Nope, sorry, tried that. The label comes straight from the database. And is translated to the storeview set in the backend.